# How do I delete tables in the QuestDB console?

Tags: questdb

I imported a lot of CSV files into my database for testing and I'd like to clear out a few of the tables I don't need. How can I get rid of multiple tables at once? Is there an easy way like selecting many tables in this view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I found was to use the REST API /exec endpoint: https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data/#exec-endpoint

I generated a bash script using the output of the "select name from tables()" Meta function.

Example lines:

```
curl -G --data-urlencode "query=DROP TABLE 'delete_me.csv'" http://localhost:9000/exec
curl -G --data-urlencode "query=DROP TABLE 'delete_me_also.csv'" http://localhost:9000/exec
```

If you use the web console (or even /exec to query) `select name from tables()` can be filtered on a regex just like a regular query.

Converting to a bash script is manual though. I recommend just dumping the table names to csv, then using bash to put in the appropriate quotes, etc.

I did it with awk:

```
awk -F, '{ print "curl -G --data-urlencode \"query="DROP TABLE \'$0\'"\" http://localhost:9000/exec"}' ~/Downloads/quest_db_drop_tables.sql > ~/Downloads/quest_db_drop_tables.sh
```